# java method stub error

Tags: java, methods

Example output:

FIXME: Finish getUserNum()

FIXME: Finish getUserNum()

FIXME: Finish computeAvg()

Avg: -1

Code I Have:

```
public class MthdStubsStatistics {

public static int getUserNum() {

System.out.println("FIXME: Finish getUserNum()");
return -1;

}

public static Integer computeAvg(){

System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg()");
return -1;
}

public static void main() {
  int userNum1 = 0;
  int userNum2 = 0;
  int avgResult = 0;

  userNum1 = getUserNum();
  userNum2 = getUserNum();

  avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);

  System.out.println("Avg: " + avgResult);

  return;
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is the computeavg method is giving me this error:

```
MthdStubsStatistics.java:23: computeAvg() in MthdStubsStatistics cannot be applied to (int,int) avgResult = computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2);
```

Comment: `computeAvg` takes no parameters, you can't call it with parameters.

Comment: When you encounter an exception you don't understand, try to create a [mcve]. This will help you track down what exactly the problem is, and makes it easier for others to help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function computeAvg with parameters computeAvg(userNum1, userNum2). In the function declaration, you need to provide those parameters:

```
public static Integer computeAvg(int userNum1, int userNum2){

//do something with userNum1 and userNum2 here

System.out.println("FIXME: Finish computeAvg()");
return -1;
}
```